# My pen does not show up

Tags: usb-drive

Please help my pen drive won't show up,
I'm new to Ubuntu ,so can't figure this out.
it won't detect in devices menu

Answer (score 0):

Check the disks utility. It is most likley formatted in a file type that Ubuntu can't use. From the disks utility you should be able to format it to something ubuntu can recognise.